# VBA word - set font styling to tables

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to set font styling only to tables after the second Word page.
so far I got:

```
Sub defaultFontStyling()

    If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
        
        Range.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        Range.Font.Size = 11
        
    End If

End Sub
```

I don't have any tables on the first page but still, it changes the font styling also there (In the entire document).

Does someone know how to fix it?

Comment: What range is `Range`?

Comment: Probably you can just use `Selection.Font.Name` and `.Size`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub defaultFontStyling()
    Dim table As table
    For Each table In ActiveDocument.Tables
        If table.Range.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) > 1 Then
            With table.Range.Font
                .Name = "Calibri"
                .Size = 11
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Getting this Error: ```compile error member already exists in an object module from which this object module derives```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/member-identifier-already-exists-in-object-module-from-which-this-object-module